# java: FileInputStream.read() reads a byte but can read a char, how come?

Tags: java, char, byte, fileinputstream

I’m testing FileInputStream, to read the text of a file (dulo.txt), the text in the file is (in ANSI):

*HELLO WORLD*

I’ve used the FileInputStream.read() method, from what I know read() can read only the next **byte** and since a char is of **2 bytes** how can the program work? Shouldn’t it crash?

This is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;



class Collections {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
      FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(new File("dulO.txt"));

      int spazioByte=fis.available();

      for(int i=0; i<spazioByte;i++){
          System.out.println("Byte: "+i+" :"+(char)fis.read());
      }



  }
}
```

Console output:

```
Byte: 0 :H
Byte: 1 :E
Byte: 2 :L
Byte: 3 :L
Byte: 4 :O
Byte: 5 : 
Byte: 6 :W
Byte: 7 :O
Byte: 8 :R
Byte: 9 :L
Byte: 10 :D
```

Comment: It depends on the encoding of your file. What is it? I guess ASCII or UTF-8...

Comment: Unless specified, `.txt` files are ANSI encoded, which is 8 bits (1 byte) per character.

Comment: yes I've saved it in ANSI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Char is 1 byte in non-unicode format. ASCII format, for example, represents char with only 1 byte.

Comment: Actually, ASCII is 7 bits. ANSI, on the other hand is 8 bit and more prevalent as the default encoding for text files.

Comment: @AshwinMukhija - I admit I thought ASCII is 8 bits. Still, my answer's still relevant :)

Comment: ASCII only supports 128 characters, which makes it 7 bit. ANSI supports 256 characters. Your answer is relevant, yes. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want read/write chars from file you can use Reader/Writer. Bellow I show simple example how use Reader

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

public class TestReader {

private final static int SIZE = 200;

       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Reader reader = new FileReader("1.txt");

            char[] buf = new char[SIZE];
            int count;
            while((count = reader.read(buf)) != -1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    System.out.println(buf[i]);
            }
            reader.close();
        }
   }
```